# Access parent controller's instance method

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've started using `ControllerAs` and `vm` variable syntax. But now I don't know how to access parent controller's method (which before I was accessing via `$scope` variable).
Here's an example of HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl as app">
  <div ng-controller="ChildCtrl as child">
  </div>
</div>
```

And corresponding controllers:

```
angular.module('test').controller('AppCtrl', function () {
  var vm = this;
  vm.log = function() {
    console.log("Output");
  }
}  

angular.module('test').controller('ChildCtrl', function () {
  var vm = this;
  // Here I want to access parent's log() function
}
```

How can I access **log()** function from `ChildCtrl`?

Comment: Try injecting `$scope` into the `ChildCtrl` and then try to access the parent scope with `$scope.$parent`. This should work.

Comment: not really an ansvar to the question - but sounds like you try to do something you should do with directives (and possibly directive controllers). Using bindings and require on directives would solve the problem.

Comment: That kind of communication between controllers is going to couple them together. You may be better off using a logger service that is injected into each.

Comment: @FlorianTopf, I've tried **$scope.$parent** syntax and my function is not visible: `TypeError: $scope.$parent.log is not a function`

Comment: @mcgraphix, Thank you. I thought maybe there's some easier way to do this not to change tonns of code that already use this function as instance method. If no, I will go with **service**.

Comment: @WhiteAngel have you tried `$scope.app` in the child since you are using controllerAs syntax? Sorry I oversaw this...

Comment: @FlorianTopf Wow, this is great! Works like a charm. You can add this as an answer and I will accept it ;) Thank you.

Comment: done. you are very welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the parent scope when using controllerAs syntax by injecting `$scope` to the child controller and using the following property:

`$scope.app`

where `app` is the name you use for the parent controller.

Comment: Great! Thank you for an answer)